# Is it possible to include subject lines in the default sendmail maillog?

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, sendmail

CentOS 5.8

I'd like to be able to track an email based on Subject line. The default log of 9 in SendMail doesn't appear to include that information.

My questions are:

- What is the minimum sendmail log level that includes this information?
- Is there a way to add the subject-line to log events at the default log level?

Answer (score 5):

I found this on the net when looking up the same thing. I didnt come up with this, but it'll get your CentOS5 box logging subjects in /var/log/maillog.

I added this to the end of my sendmail.mc:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Klog syslog
HSubject: $>+CheckSubject

LOCAL_RULESETS
SCheckSubject
R$*     $: $(log Subject: $1 $) $1
```

*****after R$* in the last line that MUST be a tab******

Run m4 and generate a new cf file and restart:

m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
/etc/init.d/sendmail restart

My logs now show this:

```
Dec  5 19:09:42 site sendmail[23327]: qB609gWD023327: from=apache, size=1728, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212060009.qB609gWD023327@myhost.edu>, relay=apache@localhost 
Dec  5 19:09:42 site sendmail[23328]: qB609gK9023328: Subject: Test1234  
Dec  5 19:09:42 site sendmail[23328]: qB609gK9023328: from=<apache@myhost.edu>, size=1953, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212060009.qB609gWD023327@myhost.edu>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=myhost.edu [127.0.0.1]
```

I wish it didnt log the subject on a seperate line, but it does allow you to track emails by subject.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by installing the [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org) milter and then supplying your own version of [filter_relay()](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) which then can call [md_syslog()](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) and log whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you won't be able to do that with a stock version of `sendmail`. You may want to roll your own by compiling sendmail after applying [a patch like this](http://www.helsinki.fi/~vmkari/smpatch.html), which should solve your problem.

Comment: Archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20160423152614/http://www.helsinki.fi/~vmkari/smpatch.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to changing your email software, Exim allows you to add the Subject to the log.  It can also be built to allow access to a database from the configuration file.  This can be used to log whatever information you want.  It is functionally equivalent to sendmail.